# Initial connection takes too long only on a specific browser/network

Tags: networking, browser, ssl

I'm having a frustrating issue that I have no idea why it happens or how to fix it.

My initial connection (the "SSL handshake") is taking a minute to some websites only on Chrome browser (latest, Version 120.0.6099.129 (Official Build) (arm64)). This I gather from 'Network' tab in the developer tool.

The same websites load reasonably fast on Safari without any issues.

The websites are github pages. For example, https://tqdm.github.io/ so I would think it's not any server issue.

(Furthermore, this only seems to happen on a particular wireless network)

I tried completely uninstalling chrome (with any Application Support files on Mac) but the problem persists.

How can I investigate this issue? Is there a tool either in command line or in browser that enables you to see the detailed trace of an http request?

Comment: Sounds like you need to tweak `chrome://settings/security`. Perhaps the browser is looking up oscp & failing, but then again...

Comment: I had the same behavior only on `Google Chrome` browser in Windows. It was a proxy timeout issue.  `Google Chrome` uses system proxy unlike some others browsers. If you are in wireless network and if you haven't proxy, try to disable it in your system (sometimes the proxy configuration is set to "auto").

Answer (score 0):

On the chrome,

- Right Click and select Inspect
- The tabs give you various information.

For instance, the Network tab will show you the times taken to load the components of the page.  It will also show you any redirections and status code for each request.